# zend framework 1 multiple library directories

Tags: zend-framework

i'm using a modular layout in zf1 and i want to create specific libraries for each module, something like this: /application/modules/default/library

while keeping the *general* library still available in: /library

the question is how do i tell ZF to load automatically all the files from those folders?
i tried using Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource with the following code in my bootstrapper

```
protected function _initLibrary()
{
    $resources = array(
        'basePath'          => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/library',
        'namespace'         => 'Default',
        'resourcesTypes'    => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'path'  => 'Form/',
                'namespace' => 'Form'
            )
        )
    );

    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource($resources);
}
```

i created a file in /application/modules/default/library/Form/AdminCreate.php which contains a class Default_Form_AdminCreate which extends Zend_Form.

however, when i tried to create an instance of this class it fails with: Fatal error: Class 'Default_Form_AdminCreate' not found

can this be achieved with Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource or am i missing something?
thanks.

Comment: You need to also insure that your  /application/modules/default/library/ is on the include_path. Use set_include_path for that in either bootstrap or even before it.

Comment: i did, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a possible solution that works for now.i am posting it here maybe someone else needs it:

```
protected function _initModules()
{       
    $modules = scandir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules');
    foreach ($modules as $m) {
        if ($m != '.' && $m != '..') {
            // Adding path for library
            set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/'.$m.'/library'), get_include_path())));   
        }

        spl_autoload_register(function($classname){
            include str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname) . '.php';
        });
    }
}
```

this function should be placed in Bootstrap.php and works if modules libraries are stored in /application/modules/*module_name*/library